# Determine T1(A) when T1 is the projection onto W1 along W2.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

The question defines $T_{1}: M_{2x2}(Q) \rightarrow  M_{2x2}(Q)$ to be the projection onto $W_{1}$ along $W_{2}$ and $T_{2}: M_{2x2}(Q) \rightarrow  M_{2x2}(Q)$ to be the projection onto $W_{2}$ along $W_{1}$. If A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix} determine $T_{1}(A), T_{2}(A)$, and $T_{1}(A)+ T_{2}(A)$.

The definition I have is that $W_{1}$ $\oplus$ $W_{2}$ = $V$ and that $T: V \rightarrow V$ projection onto $W_{1}$ along $W_{2}$ follows the rule $T(x_{1} + x_{2}) = x_{1} ;$ $ x_{1} \in W_{1}, x_{2} \in W_{2}$.

So I know that $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ are subspaces of $V$ which in this case is the 2 by 2 matrices. But having that I don't see how that relates to matrix $A$. Are the $W's$ the columns of $A$ and the $x's$ the values in those columns. Thus $T_{1}(A)$ being a single value of matrix $A$? Is this right? Am I approaching it correctly?

Thanks